# Sharing model from some window with MainWindow with MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

I have some problem with my application architecture. I need to create some application which opening some UDP socket for sending and receiving some data.

The problem is that I want to create some additional window (ConfigurationWindow) with connection configuration fields (like IP, local port, remote port). This window should be opened from MainWindow on some button click, and closed on data save command. According to MVVM, this ConfigurationWindow is creating ConfigurationViewModel which is creating ConfigurationModel which has IP and ports properties.

All is clear, but what if I want to establish a connection on 'Connect' button click in MainWindow. In MainWindowViewModel I don't have reference to ConfigurationModel from ConfigurationViewModel. I say more: after ConfigurationWindow close, ConfigurationViewModel and hence, ConfigurationModel objects doesn't exist.

What is the best way to solve this problem, how architecture of this software should looks like? Maybe the problem arises from my MVVM pattern understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution here is to have a model object you set these values on which gets shared between both viewmodels.

If you create a class with these properties on, you can then expose a static instance from the class, both viewmodels can access the same instance of data setting and getting the properties without a care for what the other is doing.

Public class Model {
  Public string IP {get; set;}

Public static Model StaticInstance {get; set}
}

Then in either viewmodel access it with...

Model.StaticInstance.IP = ...

Like I say, this is simplest. You can share the data in a number of other ways - file, registry, database if you need something more persistent.

Alternatively you make config view model available as a data source - declared in app.xaml and bindable throughout your app.

Hope these pointers help you find the solution that best fits your specific scenario.

Comment: About simplest solution: do you mean make model as a singleton? What about making ViewModel as a DataSource - can you say something more about this solution? I can't find any informations about this, and it's sound interesting.